# Java App Engine DatastoreService or PersistenceManager?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Working on a app built on GAE in java. Having trouble figuring out whether i want to use DatastoreServices and the Entity class, or make class's for my objects, and using the PersistenceManager.

Can someone explain the differences of these two services?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have a fixed reason to use either of those, take a look at [Objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/). It's a much better and more usable library for storage.

The Datastore services from the SDK are low level services that let you talk directly with Bigtable RPC. You'll be writing code that translates into Bigtable's data formats and API, and calling Bigtable's RPC methods.

The JDO specification and its persistence manager are a Java standard that deals with creating data classes and their storage and retrieval. It's one level of abstraction higher than the direct datastore services. Google has implemented the JDO spec to run on GAE, so you can use it if you want to.

Objectify is an alternative to the JDO that isn't an enterprise Java standard, but is a lot more easy and fun to use. It follows the Python API quite closely, which makes it quite nice and concise.

Comment: The benefit of course to using JDO over DatastoreService or Objectify is that you're not limited to deploying to GAE. There are JDO implementations for many storage engines, including all major RDBMS.

Answer (score 3):

My vote for DatastoreService because PersistenceManager (JDO) consumes more resources ( = more money) and it is slower.

http://gaejava.appspot.com/ — here you can compare them. Try to run this test a couple times.

Comment: Great idea and work! Can you add Objectify so that the overhead in comparison to the pure low level java API becomes more clear?