# Two different methods for Google App Engine Datastore Transactions -- which to use?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

There are two different ways to perform transactions (JDO) in the App Engine datastore.

**Method 1**: Use PersistenceManager

```
try {
   pm.currentTransaction().begin();
   // do stuff
   pm.currentTransaction().commit();
}
finally {
    if (pm.currentTransaction().isActive()) 
        pm.currentTransaction().rollback();
}
```

**Method 2**: Use DatastoreService

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService()
try {
    Transaction txn = datastore.beginTransaction();
    // do stuff
    txn.commit();
}
finally {
    if (txn.isActive()) {
        txn.rollback();
    }
}
```

What is the functional difference between these two approaches?

Comment: I believe this is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242524/java-app-engine-datastoreservice-or-persistencemanager

Comment: On a side note, I believe in both your examples, you should put the "begin" statement just outside of the try-finally. You don't really have an active transaction until the "begin" successfully returns.

Comment: it's not a duplicate of that question. Both of these code blocks do the exact same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that JDO in itself uses the low level DatastoreService APIs for transaction handling.

If you are using JDO to work with objects, you should use it's (JDOs/JPAs) persistence managers transaction methods. Otherwise, how would your objects be persisted to the underlying datastore?